# Correlation based on different group in r

Tags: r, statistics, match, correlation

I need to calculate correlation between different group in R, is there a package to do so?

For example:
I have tables like

Table1

```
Filter1 Filter2 Filter3  Month1 Month2 Month3
a1      b1      c1       12      ###     ###
a1      b2      c2       9       ###     ###
a2      b2      c1       7       ###     ###
```

Table2

```
V1  V2 Month1 Month2 Month3
x1  y1 6       ###     ###
x1  y2 5       ###     ###
```

And I want to calculate correlation with each combination of filters and also with group level:

```
F1 F2 F3 V1 V2 Cor
a1 b1 c1 x1 y1 ###
a1 b2 c2 x1 y1 ###
a2 b2 c1 x1 y1 ###
a1 b1 c1 x1 y2 ###
a1 b2 c2 x1 y2 ###
a2 b2 c1 x1 y2 ###
a1 b1    x1    ###
a2       x1    ###
all      all   ###
...........
```

So not only on drill down level but also on group-up level the correlation is been calculate.

Is there a way to do it in R?

Thank you

Comment: To calculate correlation between two variables, you need more than one point for each variable, which is not the case in your example

Comment: @EtienneKintzler, There are different month values...